# SparkException: Master removed our application

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I know there are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861588/sparkexception-job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure) [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099323/spark-driver-disassociated-and-removed-by-the-master) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732206/spark-job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure-master-removed-our-application-failed) questions on Stackoverflow but those either didn't get answered or didn't help me out. In contrast to those questions I put much more stack trace and log file information into this question. I hope that helps, although it made the question to become sorta long and ugly. I'm sorry.

## Setup

I'm running a 9 node cluster on Amazon EC2 using `m3.xlarge` instances with DSE (DataStax Enterprise) version 4.6 installed. For each workload (Cassandra, Search and Analytics) 3 nodes are used. DSE 4.6 bundles Spark 1.1 and Cassandra 2.0.

## Issue

The application (Spark/Shark-Shell) gets removed after ~3 minutes *even if I do not run any query*. Queries on small datasets run successful as long as they finish within ~3 minutes.

I would like to analyze much larger datasets. Therefore I need the application (shell) not to get removed after ~3 minutes.

## Error description

On the Spark or Shark shell, after idling ~3 minutes or while executing (long-running) queries, Spark will eventually abort and give the following stack trace:

```
15/08/25 14:58:09 ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: Master removed our application: FAILED
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Master removed our application: FAILED
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask
```

This is not very helpful (to me), that's why I'm going to show you more log file information.

### Error Details / Log Files

#### Master

From the [`master.log`](http://pastebin.com/wycQQd2Y) I think the interesing parts are

```
INFO 2015-08-25 09:19:59 org.apache.spark.deploy.master.DseSparkMaster: akka.tcp://sparkWorker@172.31.46.48:46715 got disassociated, removing it.
INFO 2015-08-25 09:19:59 org.apache.spark.deploy.master.DseSparkMaster: akka.tcp://sparkWorker@172.31.33.35:42136 got disassociated, removing it.
```

and

```
ERROR 2015-08-25 09:21:01 org.apache.spark.deploy.master.DseSparkMaster: Application Shark::ip-172-31-46-49 with ID app-20150825091745-0007 failed 10 times, removing it
INFO 2015-08-25 09:21:01 org.apache.spark.deploy.master.DseSparkMaster: Removing app app-20150825091745-0007
```

Why do the worker nodes get disassociated?

In case you need to see it, I attached the [master's executor (ID 1) `stdout`](http://pastebin.com/sRnEyL0D) as well. The executors `stderr` is empty. However, I think it shows nothing useful to tackle the issue.

On the Spark Master UI I verified to see all worker nodes to be `ALIVE`. The second screenshot shows the application details.

---

[image: Spark Master UI]

---

[image: Spark Master UI Application details]

---

There is one executor spawned on the master instance while executors on the two worker nodes get respawned until the whole application is removed. Is that okay or does it indicate some issue? I think it might be related to the "(it) failed 10 times" error message from above.

#### Worker logs

Furthermore I can show you logs of the two Spark worker nodes. I removed most of the class path arguments to shorten the logs. Let me know if you need to see it. As each worker node spawns multiple executors I attached links to some (not all) executor `stdout` and `stderr` dumps. Dumps of the remaining executors look basically the same.

**Worker I**

- [`worker.log`](http://pastebin.com/HRYSBY7s)
- [Executor (ID 10) `stdout`](http://pastebin.com/vqMqA2Zh)
- [Executor (ID 10) `stderr`](http://pastebin.com/7THRLWzA)

**Worker II**

- [`worker.log`](http://pastebin.com/J1MsJb53)
- [Executor (ID 3) `stdout`](http://pastebin.com/YG7xpnYV)
- [Executor (ID 3) `stderr`](http://pastebin.com/9mKhGh0e)

The executor dumps seem to indicate some issue with permission and/or timeout. But from the dumps I can't figure out any details.

## Attempts

As mentioned above, there are some similar questions but none of those got answered or it didn't help me to solve the issue. Anyway, things I tried and verified are:

- [Opened port 2552](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201505.mbox/%3CCAKW0i0xCQZr_6ZTGOQsHcTE0M9_G=91ExNB6sLSfOOYa+LSYMQ@mail.gmail.com%3E). Nothing changes.
- [Increased spark.akka.askTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836401/apache-spark-job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure-tid-x-failed-for-unknown-reason) which results in the Spark/Shark app to live longer but eventually it still gets removed.
- [Ran the Spark shell locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524052/unresponsive-spark-master) with `spark.master=local[4]`. On the one hand this allowed me to run queries longer than ~3 minutes successfully, on the other hand it obviously doesn't take advantage of the distributed environment.

## Summary

To sum up, one could say that the timeouts and the fact long-running queries are successfully executed in local mode all indicate some misconfiguration. Though I cannot be sure and I don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**Edit**: Two of the Analytics and two of the Solr nodes were added after the initial setup of the cluster. Just in case that matters.

**Edit (2)**: I was able to work around the issue described above by replacing the Analytics nodes with three freshly installed Analytics nodes. I can now run queries on much larger datasets without the shell being removed. I intend not to put this as an answer to the question as it is still unclear what is wrong with the three original Analytics nodes. However, as it is a cluster for testing purposes, it was okay to simply replace the nodes (after replacing the nodes I performed a `nodetool rebuild -- Cassandra` on each of the new nodes to recover their data from the Cassandra datacenter).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the attempts, the root cause is a timeout between the master node, and one or more workers.

Another thing to try:  Verify that all workers are reachable by hostname from the master, either via dns or an entry in the /etc/hosts file.

In my case, the problem was that the cluster was running in an AWS subnet without DNS.  The cluster grew over time by spinning up a node, the adding the node to the cluster.  When the master was built, only a subset of the addresses in the cluster was known, and only that subset was added to the /etc/hosts file.
When dse spark was run from a "new" node, then communication from the master using the worker's hostname failed and the master killed the job.